# Can an IActivationFactory return the same instance multiple times?

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-cx, rcw, wrl

While exploring WinRT, I made an experiment with singletons: by implementing the IActivationFactory myself, I can make a singleton "at the ABI level". The factory just returns the same instance every time. By extension, any call to RoActivateInstance for my type will return the same pointer.

It is curiously *almost* transparent when interoperating with .NET:

```
var obj1 = new MySingleton();
var obj2 = new MySingleton();

// At the .NET type level, not the same: ReferenceEquals(obj1, obj2) == false
// At the COM level, the same: Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(obj1) == Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(obj2)
```

The way I interpret this is that every instantiation generates a new RCW for the WinRT object. Thus it's not exactly the same as a singleton, but maybe close enough.

I haven't examined the other language projections.

My intention is to use this for *immutable* objects, which may not even have any constructor parameters. (If they do, the activation factory will need to keep a map of instances.) The benefit is mainly the reduced memory footprint.

But am I treading dangerous waters here? I have seen similar constructs in COM/ATL, but what about in WinRT?

Comment: This mapping [does exist](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mbend/archive/2007/04/18/the-mapping-between-interface-pointers-and-runtime-callable-wrappers-rcws.aspx).  If you don't get the same RCW back then you are certainly treading dangerous waters :)

Comment: So if I understand the following quote correctly, it really should have returned the same RCW (the quote mentions "activation"). I wonder if WinRT is somehow handled differently. *"When an IUnknown enters the system (through a marshal call, through activation, as a return parameter from a method call, etc.), we check the cache to see if an RCW already exists for the COM object. If a mapping exists, a reference to the existing RCW is returned. Otherwise a new RCW is created and a cache mapping is added."*